# Add onclick event on svg rect using Angular Renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

Is there any ways to add onclick event on svg rect.

I have tried using Angular Renderer2,

```
constructor(public renderer: Renderer2){
    const rect = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' , 'rect' );
    this.renderer.setAttribute(rect, 'onclick', 'callRect()');
}

callRect(){
console.log("Rect clicked");
}
```

But I got an error

```
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: callRect is not defined
at SVGRectElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inspite of using `setAttribute`, use [**`listen`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) method over `Renderer` by which you can call component methods directly inside `eventHandler`

```
this.renderer.listen(rect, 'click', (evt) => {
  this.callRect();
  console.log('Clicking the rect', evt);
});
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you for the example.