# Angular accessing function specified in renderer2 set property

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-renderer2

I have a directive that replaces a table value with an "a href" using [renderer.setProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002640/how-do-you-access-the-element-html-from-within-an-angular-attribute-directive).

Attached to the "a href" is a "click" property which im not sure how to access the function: "onClickAccountLink($event)" or add a programmatic function to it.

I've tried adding the same function name within the same directive but it does not seem to use the same function specified in the same file.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[AccountLink]'
})
export class AccountLink implements OnInit {

  constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let iban = this.el.nativeElement;
    if(iban) {
      this.format(iban);
    }
  }

  format(val) {
    this.renderer.setProperty(val, 'innerHTML', `<a href="javascript: void(0)" (click)="onClickAccountLink($event)">${val.innerHTML}</a>`);
    console.log(typeof(val.innerHTML)) //string
    

  }

  onClickAccountLink(event: any) {
    console.log(event)
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("function called")
  }
}
```

the directive is attached to a value in a table row.

```html
<td AccountLink>{{iban}}</td>
```

how do I make my onClickAccountLink function usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i read [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824757/add-onclick-event-on-svg-rect-using-angular-renderer2) and it solved my problem.

i added the "render.listen" to check for the click event

```js
  format(ibanValue) {
    this.renderer.setProperty(ibanValue, 'innerHTML', `<a href="javascript: void(0)">${ibanValue.innerHTML}</a>`);
    this.renderer.listen(ibanValue ,'click', ()=> {
      this.onClickAccountLink(ibanValue);
    });
  }
```